# Google ranking based on core web vitals or six web vitals?

Tags: seo, core-web-vitals

I use the google page insight https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/ to measure the perf metrics about my site. I see the overall score comes out to be based on six web vitals

1. FCP
2. SI
3. LCP
4. TTI
5. TBT
6. CLS

But recently google announce that it will consider below three vitals as core web vitals

1. FID maps to Interactiveness
2. LCP maps to Performance
3. CLS maps to Visual stability

I know google considers performance as one of the ranking factors. My question is does google rank it based on all 6 web vitals or only 3 core web vitals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Search announcement](https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2020/11/timing-for-page-experience) in November 2020, only the "Core" Web Vitals will be included in the page experience signal:

- LCP
- FID
- CLS

[image: Graphic showing CWV in the page experience signal]

See also the May 2020 announcement: https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2020/05/evaluating-page-experience

> We're combining the signals derived from **Core Web Vitals** with our existing Search signals for page experience, including mobile-friendliness, safe-browsing, HTTPS-security, and intrusive interstitial guidelines, to provide a holistic picture of page experience.

The non-core Web Vitals metrics like SI, TBT, and TTI are diagnostics to help you improve the user-centric CWVs.

Comment: With  `user-centric CWVs` you mean `LCP/CLS/FID` ?  I believe you mean  non-core Web Vitals metrics like SI, TBT, and TTI will help ultimately to improve  core web vitals LCP/CLS/FID. Is it ?

Comment: Yes, that's right

Comment: Thanks can you please also help me on https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/135649/lost-keywords-ranking-with-recent-google-core-web-release ?

Comment: Sorry, that question is very site-specific and I don't know any more about Search ranking beyond what they post publicly.